# Calculating percent change from one record to next using a SQL query

Tags: sql, join, null

I am using this query to calculate percent change of Enrollment total from current semester to the last. What changes do I need to make to this query to avoid nulls ?
I have tried using a sub query which is painfully slow.

```
SELECT E2.Term AS Prev_Term, 
       E2.[Enrollment Total] AS Prev_Enrl_Tot, 
       E1.Term,
       E1.Location, 
       E1.milestone_description, 
       E1.polling_date,
       Round(((E1.[Enrollment Total] - [Prev_Enrl_Tot]) 
                                   / [Prev_Enrl_Tot]) * 100,2) AS Percent_Change
FROM EnrollmentsByLocation E1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN EnrollmentsByLocation E2
ON E1.Location = E2.Location 
AND E1.milestone_description = E2.milestone_description 
AND E1.Term - E2.Term = 1;
```

Comment: Do you want to avoid nulls in your percent calculation (replace null with 0) or avoid rows with nulls all together (use a where clause to eliminate null rows)?

Comment: Can't just replace null rows with 0 (say, with `COALESCE`), you'd get a divide-by-zero error.  If the previous term doesn't exist, would that make the percent change 100% - so should you use a simple `CASE` statement and just output 100?

Comment: You say you want to avoid NULLs, but you don't say what behaviour you *do* want.

Comment: Change the left outer join to a join.  That way, you will get only records that are matching.

Comment: Inner join did the trick !! 
Thank you @GordonLinoff

Comment: @Dems This query was creating null values when there is no data for previous semseter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What flavor SQL?  What do you mean by  avoid nulls? Are you trying to avoid divide by zero error, or not display nulls?  Use `ISNULL`, but wrap `NULLIF` around the divisor to avoid divide by zero error.  This handles both.
Or are you trying to eliminate them from returning?  If so, look at your `LEFT` join or a `WHERE` clause.
You'll need to place your aliases on [Prev_Enrl_Tot].

```
 ISNULL(Round(((E1.[Enrollment Total] - [Prev_Enrl_Tot]) / NULLIF([Prev_Enrl_Tot],0)) * 100,2),0) AS Percent_Change
```