# Mysql query to find percentage change in the value over a time

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with values and date associated with the user and track/units he has invested in. Something like below:

```
id , track_id , user_id , value  , created_at          , updated_at,
 1 ,        7 ,       7 , 310.00 , 2014-07-11 11:55:20 , 0000-00-00 00:00:00,
 2 ,        2 ,       3 , 400.00 , 2014-07-10 00:00:00 , 0000-00-00 00:00:00,
 3 ,        2 ,       3 , 300.00 , 2014-07-11 00:00:00 , 0000-00-00 00:00:00,
 4 ,        4 ,       7 , 500.00 , 2014-07-11 09:23:17 , 0000-00-00 00:00:00,
```

I want a query to fetch my result something like

user_id, gain(%)

So basically the query would fetch top N say 3 gainers over last 7 days. My Database in MySql

Comment: ok what have you tried so far?

Comment: I am a developer and not familiar with the mysql queries very much. So whatever i tried was not fruitful so didn't post that.

Comment: ok, please post it anyways so we can help you make it work.

Comment: I followed this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13671230/how-to-calculate-percentage-increase-from-previous-row-day-after-complex-group-b

Comment: Yours is definitely a fair question - I don't know why people are marking you down.  Anyway - look here: [Join - calculating percent change from one record to next](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11366535/calculating-percent-change-from-one-record-to-next-using-a-sql-query)

Comment: i don't quite understand, did that work for you?

Comment: @FoggyDay maybe my formatting was wrong :(. No that didn't work for me. I actually couldn't understand the syntax also that's why i am posting here so that i can understand the syntax and solve my problem.

Comment: Please help me find out the solution and some useful links will be great so that i can understand what's actually happening in the query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bit of a pain.  The following query gets the minimum and maximum dates over the prior week:

```
select user_id, min(created_at) as mind, max(created_at) as maxd
from table t
where created_at >= now() - interval 7 day
group by user_id;
```

Now, you can use this to get the appropriate values by joining in:

```
select user_id, tmin.value, tmax.value
from (select user_id, min(created_at) as mind, max(created_at) as maxd
      from table t
      where created_at >= now() - interval 7 day
      group by user_id
     ) umm join
     table tmin
     on umm.user_id = tmin.user_id and umm.mind = tmin.created_at join
     table tmax
     on umm.user_id = tmax.user_id and umm.maxd = tmax.created_at;
```

This gives you the information to do the query.  Something like:

```
select user_id, tmin.value, tmax.value,
       (tmax.value - tmin.value) / tmax.value as gain_ratio
from (select user_id, min(created_at) as mind, max(created_at) as maxd
      from table t
      where created_at >= now() - interval 7 day
      group by user_id
     ) umm join
     table tmin
     on umm.user_id = tmin.user_id and umm.mind = tmin.created_at join
     table tmax
     on umm.user_id = tmax.user_id and umm.maxd = tmax.created_at;
```

Comment: Thank you so much.. It solved my problem.. I can't vote for your answer as it requires minimum 15 reputation.

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you need, I returned the old/new value for illustration, you can remove them from the select list if you just want the user id and % gain -

```
select x.user_id,
       x.value as new_val,
       y.value as prev_val,
       (y.value / x.value - 1) * 100 as gain_pct
  from tbl x
  join tbl y
    on x.user_id = y.user_id
 where x.created_at =
       (select max(z.created_at)
          from tbl z
         where z.user_id = x.user_id
           and z.created_at between date_sub(current_date, interval 7 day) and
               current_date)
   and y.created_at =
       (select min(z.created_at)
          from tbl z
         where z.user_id = x.user_id
           and z.created_at between date_sub(current_date, interval 7 day) and
               current_date)
order by gain_pct desc
limit 3
```

Use LIMIT to return top 3, 5, 10, etc.

Fiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/037243/10/0